# Best/Standard way to store email addresses for a mail list?

Tags: php, html, email

I am working on adding a mail list to a website which is php enabled. I know how to create a form, pass the variables to a php file, and then use that php file to store the variables in the root directory for the website. However, this just seems to insecure. I tried saving all of the files to a database, however I do not have access to a MySQL site, nor can I figure out how to access a database in the root directory of the website.

So I am just wondering if I am going about this the wrong way, or is there something I am missing. I have never really seen any examples of mail lists or how they work, so this concept is new to me. Thanks in advance for the help.

**EDIT**
Sorry for the confusion. What I mean with the MySQL is that I am trying to figure out if that is the standard way before going through the trouble of learning to setup and run one. If it is then I will take the time to, but if this is not the way, then I would rather spend the time on another project.

Comment: What host are you using without mysql? If you're going to store them in  plaintext files, store them away from the publicly accessible pages. This is normally (from the main /index.php) just `../emails.txt`. Make sure you can read that in your webhost before using it. If that's not available, you can always store them encrypted but... I'd rather prefer to receive each in an email and store them offline (for < 1000s)

Comment: answer to the subject line is "in a data base" but the question text is hard to understand

Comment: I don't have access to a MySQL site because, 1) I don't really know how to set one up 2) I am hosting the server on a private LAN (Mongoose v3.8 for windows) for testing purposes before uploading 3) I don't know if the server I am uploading to is MySQL enabled. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: *"I have never really seen any examples of mail lists or how they work"* – Google `plain text newsletter php` you'll find many results. As for the maintenance of a flatfile newsletter, forget it; you're wasting your time. You will find something that could be "OK", but make sure it has a function that will let people unsubscribe themselves, otherwise it's going to be absolute mayhem.

Comment: 1- well learn how, if you want the "Best/Standard" way

Comment: MySql - or any db is the standard way.

Comment: Creating a (PHP) file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` will show you if the `mysql/mysqli/pdo` libraries are on the server.

Comment: This question shows a clear lack of understanding about programming and storage. Because if this it is impossible to provide you a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below shows you how u can carry out the task. The email from the form is saved in the $email variable and a 
(line break ) is concatenated so that the values can be separated later on when you fetch the contents of file. Then the fopen() function creates a email_list.txt file and appends all the following entries in the file.the file is created in the same directory where this php file resides. the form and php code both must be in the same page.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email@example.com">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save">

</form>



<?php

 if(isset($_POST['save'])){

  $email = $_POST['email'].",";


  $handler = fopen('email_list.txt','a');
  if(fwrite($handler,$email)){
    echo "Email saved successfully";
  }

  }


 ?>
```

best of luck

Comment: Thanks mate.I have corrected the answer :) @PeeHaa

Comment: Thank you for this. I hope to improve to a MySQL database when I can, but for now this will work great.

Answer (score 1):

The best/standard way to do this is a database (MySQL is a decent choice). There are other options but none will be as clean and SQL skills are something you *will* need in the future if you are doing any serious PHP programming so it is will worth picking them up.

Just use the SQL client to construct/test the queries you want to make - then take those same queries and use the PHP statements to make them. Be aware of SQL injection attacks so escape those strings!

Alternatively if all you need is a mailing list there are plenty of free "mailing list" tools out there.